# How to remove Microsoft forced homepage on all browsers?

Tags: browser

I am not sure what the real cause is, but recently I installed the Microsoft OneDrive on my Win 10 computer. Since then, every time I open a new browser (be that in chrome, firefox, and IE), they're all redirected to first for a split second http://go.microsoft.com/?69157, then quickly re-redirected into https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/. I have tried resetting the default homepage on these browsers but somehow the microsoft page seems to overwrite them all. Also, my Avast Antivirus kept identifying this issue: `SVC: eCrrrA > C:\ProgramData\eCrrrA` (as `Win64:Trojan-gen`), it shows back up even though I kept deleting or moving it to virus chest.

Am I getting some virus or malware? And how do I remove the forced homepage?

Comment: That's what Avast is telling me.

Comment: It also affects internet explorer. Do you suggest uninstalling these browsers and reinstalling again? What exactly may be the cause?

Comment: Until you get your computer cleaned up from malware there’s no sense in even talking about your browsers. That should be what your conversation is about.